# Populating textbox with data based on dropdown list selection (onChange)

Tags: c#, ajax, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I am building a website using ASP.NET MVC and entity framework.
I have a DB table with Country info:

```
CountryID int;
ShortName nvarchar;
CountryCode nvarchar;
```

In my View I have:

```
<div class="editor-field"><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.address.CountryID, Model.countriesList, "<--Select Country-->") %></div>
<div class="display-field"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.phone.CountryCode)%>></div>
```

The list I pass onto the view is:

```
countriesList = new SelectList(countries, "CountryID", "ShortName");
```

**Update** The javascript code:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#address.CountryID").change(function()
    {
        $.get("/PersonalInfo/GetCountryCode", $(this).val(), function(data)
        {
            $("#phone.CountryCode").val(data);
        });
    });
});
```

And the controller method:

```
public ActionResult GetCountryCode(int id)
    { 
        Country c = personalInfoRepository.GetUserCountryByID(id);
        string countryCode = c.PhoneCode;
        return Content(countryCode);
    }
</script>
```

What I want to do is to populate the display field with the corresponding CountryCode every time the user selects a different country from the dropdown. I understand ajax can be used to achieve this but unfortunatelly I have no experience with it. I would appreciate any help with the code or some links to easy enough tutorials for beginners.

Would it be possible to do it without posting back to the server if I passed a countryCodeList along the countriesList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a great tutorial with 3 different methods for creating cascading dropdowns with ASP.NET MVC - http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/09/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-41-creating-cascading-dropdown-lists-with-ajax.aspx

The concept for populating a textbox will be similar. First of all you will need a controller action that will return the correct country code for a given country:

```
public ActionResult GetCountryCode(int countryId)
{
    //logic to find country code goes here
    string countryCode = "1";
    return Content(countryCode);
}
```

Now you will need some javascript to bind to the change event of your country dropdown and call your controller action via ajax. I recommend using jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#address_CountryID").change(function()
        {
            $.get("/Countries/GetCountryCode", $(this).val(), function(data)
            {
                $("#phone_CountryCode").val(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I came across the tutorial you mentioned before posting but couldn't make it work. I'm sure your suggestion is correct but I am so new to programming that I can't make it work either... The JS function doesn't fire.

Comment: Tsarl, if the onChange event isn't firing, you might not be accessing the element correctly. Inthe above example, it was suggested that the element could be accessed via $("#address.CountryID"), but #address.CountryID might not necessarily be the real id for the dropdownlist. If you inspect the HTML rendered, can you see the drowndownlist? If so, what is it's id value?

Comment: Well I meant that the JS doesn't work... not even sure if it means the same thing. The id is address.CountryID. The only change I had to make was the .get path

Comment: Post your JavaScript and maybe we can fix it

Comment: I think the original id selectors I provided were invalid. Try replacing the periods with underscores like I have done above. You can use the console in firebug or the chrome developer tools to test this out. Executing $("#address_CountryID").val() in the console should return a value if that id is correct. Other than that the javascript looks good assuming the paths are correct.

Comment: $("#address_CountryID").val() works fine now, getting the right index but then the script never get to the $("#phone_CountryCode").val(data);
 part. I get this error: GET http://localhost:26925/PersonalInfo/GetCountryCode500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Changed the path to "/PersonalInfoController/GetCountryCode" but now I get this error GET http://localhost:26925/PersonalInfoController/GetCountryCode?2 
404 Not Found

Comment: You don't need Controller in the path. "/PersonalInfo/GetCountryCode" is what you need